# Calculating value in JasperReports scriptlet AFTER a group is printed

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have the following JasperReport scriptlet, it works fine:

```
public class ReportScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

    public void beforeGroupInit(String groupName)  throws JRScriptletException {
        System.out.println("in beforeGroupInit - " + groupName);
    }

    public void afterGroupInit(String groupName)  throws JRScriptletException {
        System.out.println("in afterGroupInit - " + groupName);
    }

}
```

The issue is that `beforeGroupInit` and `afterGroupInit` run BEFORE the lines of the group are printed, and I need to make a calculation AFTER the lines are printed.

Since there is no `afterGroupFinalized` event, is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the GroupFooter? You can create a new variable, set your calculation and set the right field in the variable expression

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did. I set an expression like `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.myFunction()` in a variable in a group footer, that triggered the calculation